# how to set background image full height-width in large screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

- i was put .svg file as background image.
- in small screen it was ok, but when i show in large screen it was cut from top and bottom
- i want to show background image in full height/width as original size in large and all screen

demo image

[image: in large screen]

-here is my code

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 540px;
  background-image: url(http://inheritxdev.net/Design-Projects/perfit_home/images/OnePager-Header.svg);
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<div class="bg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the div height = pageHeight(header height and appropriate margins should be minus).

```css
.bg{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - (2em + 18px)); /* p tag margin = 2em(1em top, 1em bottom ; p tag height = 18px) */
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535498730771-e735b998cd64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80); /* I changed an image because your image not showing in the playground */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think it has to do with the background-size.
Maybe this works better for you? (practically the same, btw if `contain` isn't what you want try `cover`.

```
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

could you prehaps show what you want with an image.

Comment: Ah that's because it tries to compensate for the width and height based on the parameters set... But do you want to have it always 100% width but strech/squash the image in the height or not?

Comment: you could prehaps use something like this if you want to use cover to keep 100% width but keep the height filled and the picture aligned from the top. `
background-position-y: top;
background-size: cover;`

Comment: please share your code. i can't understand what you talking about.

Comment: i put that background-position-y: top; background-size: cover; ,but now image crop from bottom.